# Add an element to the DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want add an element with JavaScript.

I have the following code:

```
var collection = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.innerHTML = 'some text';
collection.item(0).firstChild.appendChild(a);
```

and simple HTML:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Where is mistake?

Answer (score 36):

This should do what you are looking for:

```js
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("some text"));
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

First, you create the element by `document.createElement`. To set its text contents, you have to have a "text node" wrapping your text. So, you first create such text node and then add it as (the only) child to your new object.

Then, add your newly created DIV element to the DOM structure. You don't have to look for the BODY element with `getElementsByTagName()`, since it exists as a property of `document` object.

Comment: but It was only example, when I will want getElementsByTagName('xyz') and create element createElement('abc') and set  innerHTML="<a href "some url">text</a>" ....How can I do that?

Comment: Just a heads up, you should always go with `documentFragment` when adding multiple elements. `documentFragment` acts as a staging area where you repeatedly add elements and, at last, you add it to the `DOM`. Repeatedly adding elements to the `DOM` will cause entire document reflow. See this: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Answer (score 6):

Your code is failing because at the time you try to insert that brand new div, the body tag is empty, and therefore there's no firstChild to append anything to. Change your last line to:

```
collection.item(0).appendChild(a);
```