# Creating button element with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

[On My Demo Page](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos) I'm trying to create a button which will inevitably be used to close the modals. I tried this code:

```
x=document.createElement('button'); x.className='superclose';
```

[In File tinybox.js](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/tinybox.js)

The CSS looks like this:

```
.superclose {position:absolute; top: 50px; left:50px; width:150px; height:50px;}
```

However I cannot get the button to show up. I thought that something must be wrong when executing the whole modal code so I tried to launch this in  Firebug just to create the button out of the blue and that didn't work either.

Anyone have any recommendations please?

Also, how do I set the text of the button? I tried to find the corresponding 'attribute' but couldn't find one for the text of buttons.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you adding the button to the DOM somewhere? Only creating it does not add it to the tree. You have to tell the document where it should be placed.

Comment: ..Aha. Sooo, adding a class and setting the location via css doesn't work then? So how would I go about adding the button to the DOM?

Comment: It does work. You're assigning the element to a variable. After doing that you need to append it to the document.

Comment: The CSS is only applied to elements in the DOM tree. See [add element to the DOM with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439642/add-element-to-the-dom-with-js). If you want to use jQuery I suggest to read its tutorials and documentation (you tagged the question with jQuery but you are using the plain DOM interface, so I'm not sure what you are after).

Comment: Try like this http://jsfiddle.net/VnqMv/1/, btw nice photo in demo page :)

Comment: Cool, so I tried this code `x=document.createElement('button'); 
x.className='superclose'; 
x.setAttribute("id", "tclose2"); 

$('#tclose2').append($('tbox'));` and this is the error I get: `TypeError: $("#tclose2") is null
[Break On This Error]  

$('#tclose2').append($('tbox'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets make it official:

You have to add the element to the DOM. Only creating it does not add it to the tree.

The CSS is only applied to elements in the DOM tree. See [add element to the DOM with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439642/add-element-to-the-dom-with-js).

If you want to use jQuery I suggest to read its [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) (you tagged the question with jQuery but you are using the plain DOM interface, so I'm not sure what you are after).

You can set the content of an element with `innerHTML`:

```
x.innerHTML = 'Some Text';
```

With jQuery, the whole process would simply be:

```
// creates the button and adds it to the body
$('<button />', {'class': 'superclose', text: 'Some Text'}).appendTo(document.body);
```