# Creating multiple instances of the same id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question I can't seem to figure out myself.

Say I have created a paragraph that says "+1". When I click a button that already exists in my code, I can make this paragraph appear above the button and I can transform it so that it's 'y' increases and it moves up while fading slowly.

So, you click the button, a +1 appears above and moves up while fading.

How do I make it so I can create a new instance of this +1 without removing the first one if I click the button before the first one has a chance to disappear?

So, if I clicked the button really fast, a stream of +1's would appear above the button and slowly fade out, one by one. Any idea of how I would go about doing this?

Thank you!!

Comment: what does `the same id` have to do with your question? on that note, HTML id's must be unique - odd behaviour can ensue if they are not

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/2439642/1072229

Comment: @Jaromanda X Because if I create a text with the id "+1" and make it move upwards and fade out, then spawn in that same "+1" with another click, it will not be in its original location but rather faded out far above the button because the CSS has told the previous "+1" to do so. Does that make sense, or am I being delusional?

Comment: having the same text (paragraph that says "+1" in your question) has nothing to do with an element having the same `id` - I fail to understand your comment

Comment: I apologise for any confusion caused, the title was not meant to be misleading. What I would like to know is how to create multiple instances of an element (in my case <p>) that is assigned to follow a set of actions, and does not effect the other existing instances of that element.

Comment: So, in my case, a button that creates a "+1" above the button itself. The "+1" would then move upwards slowly while fading out. If the button was clicked rapidly, a long stream of these moving "+1" 's would be formed. Thank you.

Comment: @Jaromanda X Exactly like cookie clicker: http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using jQuery:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var $newPlus = $('<div class="plus">+1</div>');
 $('#area').append($newPlus);
  setTimeout(function(){ $newPlus.addClass('fade'); }, 50);
  setTimeout(function(){ $newPlus.remove(); }, 650);
});
```

```css
#area {
  position: relative;
  padding: 70px;
}
#area .plus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: top 300ms ease-out, opacity 600ms ease-in-out;
}
#area .plus.fade {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area">
  <button>Plus One</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Look, this is perfect but I'm completely new to JQuery. How would I implement this into my HTML-Javascript document? Please run me through if you can.

Comment: @Caspar simply wrap the JQuery block on <script></script> tags same as JavaScript.