# When you make changes to a site using the browser's dev tools, does the elements tab update?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools, getelementbyid, devtools

Note: I'm using Chrome's dev tools.

I created a section under the header using the console.

Under the console's dev tools I type:

```
var Europe = document.createElement('section');
// undefined
Europe
// <section></section>
Europe.setAttribute('id', 'europe')
```

When I go the elements tab, I'm not seeing the section at all.

If I update the .js file, save it, and then reload the browser, would that cause the element tree to change?

I'm working on some DOM hw and it's really giving me a hard time.

.js file:

```
console.log("test");

var citizens = ['Anka', 'Wallace', 'Pierre', 'Juan'];

var cuisines = ['French', 'English', 'Spanish', 'Russian'];

var body = document.querySelector('body');

function makeLocation() {
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code you're using?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher hey--I had a few words in <> which caused them to disappear. I just fixed it.

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher Sure thing. I also switched the text around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an element to the DOM with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439642/add-an-element-to-the-dom-with-javascript)

Comment: @Tsardines your js file is nearly empty, your edit didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the code to insert the new `Element` into the DOM. You can use the function `.insertAdjacentElement` to add your new `section` to the DOM, after the header like this:

```
// ... after your code creating the variable Europe

let header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];

header.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', Europe);
```

After you run this code, you should see the new `section` appear in the 'Elements` tab in the developer tools - you should also see it appear on the page.

**Note:** If you click 'Refresh' in chrome, any changes you made in the chrome developer tools will be deleted since the browser will pull the code from the source again.

Hope this helps!