# Adding a second element while iteratively adding an element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object which I want to iteratively add to HTML using JS. On the right of each object I wanted to add a button to it.

Say, my object looks something like `{"one": "One", "two": "Two", "three": "Three"}`

The end result, it should look like this:

```
- One [Click Me]
- Two [Click Me]
- Three [Click Me]
- etc...
```

HTML:

`<ul id="container"></ul>`

JS:

```
const container = document.getElementById("container")
const obj = {"one": "One", "two": "Two", "three": "Three"}

for(let key in obj) {
  const listItem = document.createElement("li")
  const listButton = document.createElement("button")

  listButton.textContent = "Click me!"
  listItem.textContent = obj[key]

  // Unsure how to add the button
  // Tried:
  //
  // const tempButton = document.createElement('button');
  // tempButton.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  // listItem.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', tempButton)
  //
  // also tried:
  //
  // listItem.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', '<div>Hello</div>')
  container.appendChild(listItem)
}
```

I am seeing the `"One" "Two" "Three"` as expected, but no button. How can I add/insert/append an additional element next to my iteration? Is there a more efficient way than what I am currently proposing?

Comment: Check out this answer and see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439642/add-an-element-to-the-dom-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the `button` as a child to the `li` element.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container")
const obj = {"one": "One", "two": "Two", "three": "Three"}

for(let key in obj) {
  const listItem = document.createElement("li");
  const listButton = document.createElement("button");

  listButton.textContent = "Click me!"
  listButton.style.margin = '10px';
  listItem.textContent = obj[key];
  listItem.appendChild(listButton);

  container.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

```html
<ul id="container"></ul>
```