# Can't retrieve data from the NY Times API

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the largest `image`, `title`, `short description` and `url` of top stories from the NY Times API. Before I get all the information that I need, I'm trying to just get the titles but I can't seem to get any information appearing. Is something wrong with my code?
[image]

UPDATE: I've added the element to the DOM (please see code below) however the title still hasn't been displayed. I also tried printing it in the console before but nothing printed there either.

```
var url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=MY_API_KEY'
function setup() {
    noCanvas()
    loadJSON(url, gotData)
}

function gotData(data) {
const articles = data.results

for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    const title = document.createElement('h1') 
    title.innerText = articles[i].title 
    document.body.appendChild(title)
}
}
```

Comment: can you also post the errors which you see on javascript console

Comment: You are creating the element but never adding them to the DOM. At least in the code you've shown.

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary I'm not receiving any errors, it just won't print.

Comment: thanks for the API key - adding it to the list of API keys posted in questions on stackoverflow

Comment: @Rahni -as has already been stated, you are creating two elements for each title (why two) ... but doing nothing with them, they don't just appear at a random place in the DOM, you have to put them where you want them

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for your comment. How would I add them to the DOM?

Comment: [Add an element to the DOM with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439642/add-an-element-to-the-dom-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. I answered in your dupe but here is better

```js
let html = [];
fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=yourApiKey')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    data.results.forEach(res => {
      html.push(`<h1>${res.title}</h1>`);
    })
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = html.join("");
  })
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you created your element, but you still need to add it to the DOM.

---

To create your element:

`const title = document.createElement('h1')`

And to add it to the DOM (to make it actually appear on your page):

`document.body.appendChild(title)`

---

But now you still need to add your actual title from the API to it:

`title.innerText = articles[i].title`

And all together:

```
const title = document.createElement('h1') // create the heading
title.innerText = articles[i].title // add the title from the API to your heading
document.body.appendChild(title) // add your heading to the DOM (this will make it appear)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used the code you provided to add the element to the DOM which has helped however nothing is still printing. Perhaps it's related to how I've retrieved the information from the API.

Comment: @Rahni Check if the API actually returns what you think it should return, and also check if you handle the response correctly. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I've included an image in my question which shows what the API returns so it does return the data but when I copy the url and write the JavaScript to get it to print in the console, nothing prints therefore I'm probably not handling the response correctly.

Comment: @Rahni I think you may want to ask another question about how to handle the response. Right now it's hard to tell what the problem might be, and also a separate question would help to distinguish between the two problems you're facing.

Comment: I will do so if I can't solve it, hopefully that will help.