# To do app - adding items to a list. What am I missing here...?

Tags: javascript

I'm new with Javascript and trying to add an item to a list. I can't edit the HTML, CSS, only add vanilla javascript.

Here is what I have for javascript so far:

```
  (function(){


  const additeminput = document.querySelector('todo-input');
  const additembutton = document.querySelector('todo-btn');

  additembutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = additeminput.value;
  })

})();
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title">Today's To Do List</h3>
    <form id="todo-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-input" placeholder="What else do you need to do?">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="todo-btn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" value="Add Item To List">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="todo-ul">
    <li class="list-group-item">Pick up groceries
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Finish essay
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Soccer @ 5:00

        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your `document.createElement('li')` stays only in memory. You must append this element to DOM if you want to see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an element to the DOM with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439642/add-an-element-to-the-dom-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the `<li>` you created to the `<ul>`:

```js
const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-ul');
```

And then in the `eventListener` after you add `textContent` add:

```js
todoList.appendChild(li)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just a few more changes:

You need to change the type of the button to `"button"` instead of submit to prevent form submission.

```
<input type="button" id="todo-btn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" value="Add Item To List">
```

And now, add the newly created `li` element to the list:

```
  const additeminput = document.querySelector('#todo-input');
  const additembutton = document.getElementById('todo-btn');
  const list = document.getElementById('todo-ul');

  additembutton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = additeminput.value;
    list.appendChild(li);
  })
```

You can get an element from the page by its ID by using:

```
document.getElementById('id')
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#id')
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it's incorrect

```
  const additeminput = document.querySelector('todo-input');
  const additembutton = document.querySelector('todo-btn');
```

it should be

```
 const additeminput = document.querySelector('#todo-input');
 const additembutton = document.querySelector('#todo-btn');
```

then you should append your `li` element into `group-list`

```
const listGroup = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');
listGroup.appendChild(li)
```

as far as you use `<input type="submit"` add into your event listener 
`e.preventDefault()` to avoid reloading

```
 additembutton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
```