# create list item from input value

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm working on a to-do list project and I got a problem, I want that when I click on the submit button the input value becomes a list item but it doesn't work.
here's the code:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let txt = document.getElementById('txt')

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let list = document.createElement('li')
    list.innerHTML = txt.value
})
```

```html
<h1 id="title">To do list</h1>
    <div class="main">
        <input type="text" alt="type text here" id="txt">
        <button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an element to the DOM with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439642/add-an-element-to-the-dom-with-javascript)

Comment: If the button is in a form, the form submit will happen before the JS completes.  You either need to interrupt the default action of a submit button or change the button to type `button` in order to allow any JS DOM manipulation to occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `document.body.appendChild(list);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a ul (if it is to be an unordered list) element in your document - or to create one with JS, and then you need to add the new list items to that (not to the body).

Try this snippet (where the ul element is already in the document)

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let txt = document.getElementById('txt')
let ul = document.getElementById('ul');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let list = document.createElement('li')
  list.innerHTML = txt.value;
  ul.appendChild(list);
})
```

```html
<h1 id="title">To do list</h1>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" alt="type text here" id="txt">
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<ul id="ul">
</ul>
```